# Authenticate the device certificate signed by CA

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot

I have created my device certificate signed by my CA (previously registered with AWS IoT), what AWS API call do I use to associate it to my device in the registry. To be more specific the steps that I am trying to achieve are the following:
1) Register my CA with AWS IoT.
2) Create a thing entry in the registry for my device.
3) Generate a certificate for my device signed by my CA.
4) Associate the certificate created above with device created in the registry so that it can be authenticated when it connects.

How do I perform step 4) programmatically using the API or AWS-SDK in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AttachThingPrincipal API. This api can associate principal (such as a certificate or other credential) with device created in the registry.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I'm new to AWS but according to my knowledge the principal API can take certificate ARN in principal parameter. Actually we have 3 items to authenticate. 1.) ECC certificate 2.) ECC Key (Private Key) and 3.) CA certificate. Using these certificate received from the device, the app will then subscribe to the AWS-IOT thing shadow. I am not able to get whether we have to use an or AWS-SDK methods

Comment: @Tripatpal If you have your own certificates then you can upload and register that with [AWS IOT](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-your-own-certificate-with-aws-iot/). And then you can attach the uploaded certificate with the device.